# How to use a LaTeX beamer (template)

Tags: beamer, templates

This is a really stupid question (I know) but I can't figure out how to get this LaTeX beamer template: http://blog.barisione.org/2007-09/torino-a-pretty-theme-for-latex-beamer/

I get a tar-file and zip it. But how to use the template? When I click on it I just get into a lot of different files.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is a README file in the tarball... it has instructions for how to install the theme on Unix like systems. You can check that out. If you need help for other OSes, you should specify that OS `:-)`

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Actually, there is no need to sign your name, it will be shown at the lower right corner automatically.

Comment: One option would be to unpack all files in your working folder but it's better to `install` it following next instrucctions: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/1952)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read the Beamer user manual. A Beamer theme is a file with the name `beamertheme<name>.sty`. The Torino theme is called `beamerthemeTorino.sty`. Place this and the other files in the directory where you are working. In your Beamer document write this command:

```
\usetheme{Torino}
```

and write your presentation as usual.

If you want to use the theme in several presentations, unpack the files in your TEXMF tree (the directory where all TeX builtin stuff is stored), and run `texhash` to update the filename database.